# Milestone Actions-Field update is not triggering on existing cases

Tags: entitlements

I have a created new version of entitlement process by adding a milestone action of time trigger field update under violation Actions.

I added a condition that a custom checkbox field should be marked as true when milestone is violated under violation actions by adding a time trigger of 0 minutes of after SLA violated.

And ran a entitlement process update rule to update the existing records.

Now this is working fine when a new case is created and it is violated but it is not working for the existing violated cases.

Am I missing anything  here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entitlement process needed to be in place at the time the existing records would have triggered the Milestone for it to have any impact on those records. Time started running when the records were created. For existing records, the "event" that would have triggered the Milestone Action has already passed and cannot trigger the new entitlement process.